# How do I analyze the 'CBS.log' file generated by the 'sfc' command to detect corrupt files in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, sfc

I have some problems with my Windows 7 system so I've ran `sfc /scannow`. I'm getting this message:

> Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files and was unable to fix some of them...

I also searched the folder of the log file to find the `cbs.log`. I then ran this command to pull out the actual problems/corrupt files:

```
findstr /c:"[SR]" %windir%\Logs\CBS\CBS.log >"%userprofile%\Desktop\sfcdetails.txt"
```

This command created an `sfcdetails` text file [(download)](http://www.datafilehost.com/download-643eed30.html).

Can someone help me analyze this file? I haven't found a detailed article about it so far.

Comment: I get a addware warning from avira on the linked site.

Comment: The "CBS.log reader and analyser" by Batchapp aka KSofiane is still downloadable, via suspicious-looking commission download-pages. File Version 2.0.0.0, size 300544 bytes, compilation timestamp 2016-03-04 21:21:13, gets flagged by 4 scanners out of 69, at:
[virustotal.com/gui/file/be67ac1da4ec9c3d7d7afe5ab58b9351b28a779cc559ca422e5129abebba0b7d](https://virustotal.com/gui/file/be67ac1da4ec9c3d7d7afe5ab58b9351b28a779cc559ca422e5129abebba0b7d)

Answer (score 5):

## ***Answer :***

You can manually make search for those text :

> - "corrup"
> - "repair"
> - "Repairing corrupted file"
> - "Cannot repair member file"
> - "Repaired file"
> - "[SR]"

[image: Capture]

## ***Alternative Answer :***

Use the application "Read and analyze Cbs.log"

*Update (as of 2020): **warning** the official download [link](https://batchapp.webs.com/miscellaneous.htm) for this application is dead, proceed with caution.*

[image: Capture]

---

**[Additional details](https://support.microsoft.com/en-en/kb/928228)** on the Microsoft's documentation

Comment: The batchapps link now directs user into a black hole of unknown websites and which attempts to cozen you into downloading some BS downloader that boasts it will direct the user to free 4K movies. It's too bad this turned into a garbage link,

Comment: @NothingToSeeHere answer updated...

Answer (score 0):

your log is clean, no corrupt files were found,

```
2012-08-26 21:25:12, Info CSI    00000359 [SR] Repairing 0 components
```

Comment: Tnx man but how can that be? - according to this there is something "....found corrupt files and was unable to fix..."

Comment: I don't know, it should have logged the corrupt files in that log, but did not.

Comment: interesting - il try to run the command in winpe and see what il get

Comment: I just ran the command "sfc /verifyonly" and my log looks just like yours, verify only does not repair anything, it said no integrity violations found at the end of the scan.

Comment: very interesting, cause i did ran it in scannow switch as always..

Comment: rename your cbs log file to CBS.log.BAK, rerun SFC /scannow

Comment: Ya its the same as delete the file as i did. same results