# Windows 7 CBS.log permissions

Tags: windows-7, file-permissions, event-log

`C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log` is currently some 16MB and rather unwieldy to look through. Also, it has restricted permissions so I cannot open it in a text editor. Will changing the CBS.log file permissions compromise it's system use (e.g. `sfc/scannow`)?

Per [this similar question](https://superuser.com/q/466651/630402), I see that there are some options to parse pertinent data, but was wondering if I could just move or rename the text file and replace it with a blank text file of the same name to get the latest results of `sfc/scannow`?

[image]

Comment: If the CBS.log file is locked (due to a process using it, which often happens, especially after running an SFC or alike), make a copy of it and then open the copy in Notepad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image shows you had an admin Command Prompt open. All you had to do was entering the following command:

```
notepad C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log
```

Then, you could use Notepad to view the file and save the file elsewhere.

And no, changing its permission, moving it or deleting it does not hurt anyone or anything. It is a log file after all.